# Sprite Kit, Delay on button press

Tags: sprite-kit

I am writing a sprite kit game which uses buttons, They are a very important bit of the game. The problem is I need them to have delays, So say you can only press it every 5 minutes. Thanks in advance for your help.

.H file

```
    typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ButtonState)
    {
        On,
        Off
    };

    @interface Button2 : SKLabelNode

    - (instancetype)initWithState:(ButtonState) setUpState;
    - (void) buttonPressed;

    @end
```

.M file

```
@implementation Button2 
{
    ButtonState _currentState;
}

- (id)initWithState:(ButtonState) setUpState
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _currentState = setUpState;
        self = [Button2 labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
        self.text = [self updateLabelForCurrentState];
        self.fontSize = 30;

    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *) updateLabelForCurrentState
{
    NSString *label;

    if (_currentState == On) {
        label = @"Sell";

    }
    else if (_currentState == Off) {

    }

    return label;
}

- (void) buttonPressed
{
    if (_currentState == Off) {
        _currentState = On;

    }
    else {
        _currentState = Off;
    }

    self.text = [self updateLabelForCurrentState];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the touch delegates are being implemented in the scene using which you find the node at the touchPoint and call the buttonPressed method on it.

You can set up a bool flag which can be set when the button is pressed.

In your .h file:

```
@property BOOL interactionAllowed;
```

You can access this property in the touch delegate of the scene like:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:touchPoint];

    if ([node isKindOfClass:[Button2 class]])
    {
        Button2 *button = (Button2*)node;
        if (button.interactionAllowed)
        {
            [button buttonPressed];
        }
    }
}
```

As for setting (and resetting) the interactionAllowed property:

```
- (void) buttonPressed
{
    if (_currentState == Off) {
        _currentState = On;
        self.interactionAllowed = NO;

        [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:3000], [SKAction runBlock:^{
            self.interactionAllowed = YES;
        }]]]];

    }
    else {
        _currentState = Off;
    }

    self.text = [self updateLabelForCurrentState];
}
```

Comment: I am getting 1 error and 1 warning, I can't work out how to fix them.
Error - Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2
Warning Incompatible pointer types sending 'SKAction *' to parameter of type 'NSArray *'

Comment: Please check the edited answer... I was writing this code directly and missed putting the sequence objects in an array

Comment: Thanks man, Also would you know how I could display that on screen?

Comment: Display what exactly?

Comment: The time counting down?